# Quad-precision numbers with Intel Compiler (icc)

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754, icc, quadruple-precision

I have been trying to work with Intel's Quad-precision floats. I have the following code, and it is returning unexpected results.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int print(const char *label, _Quad r) {
  int prec = 20;
  int width = 46;
  char buf[128];

  int n = quadmath_snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%+-#*.36Qe", width, r);
  printf ("%s: %s\n", label, buf);
  return 0;
}

int main () {
  _Quad x = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288q;
  print("value", x);
  print("log", logq(x));
  print("log10", log10q(x));
  print("cos", cosq(x));
  print("sin", sinq(x));
  print("sqrt", sqrtq(x));
}
```

This program returns the following results:

```
value: +3.141592653589793238462643383279502797e+00   
log: +7.644623500000000000000000000000000000e+07   
log10: -6.174980530000000000000000000000000000e+08   
cos: +0.000000000000000000000000000000000000e+00   
sin: +0.000000000000000000000000000000000000e+00   
sqrt: -1.994699018000000000000000000000000000e+09
```

It looks like the quad-precision literal is being interpreted correctly. However, the functions `logq`, `log10q`, `cosq`, `sinq` and `sqrtq` are returning incorrect results.

The only directions I've found regarding Intel's `_Quad` type is [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/How-to-use-quadruple-precision-Quad-data-type/td-p/1168090).

I am compiling this code on MacOS with:

```
icc -fPIC -wd1572 -Qoption,cpp,--extended_float_type -Wconversion -lquadmath -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10 test.c
```

Am I using the quad-precision math functions correctly?

Also, I have tried to use the function pattern as described in [this post](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/How-to-use-quadruple-precision-Quad-data-type/m-p/1168094/highlight/true#M36056).

> Quadruple precision analogs of libm functions have '__' prefix (double underscore) and 'q' suffix."

However, this results in `NaN` returned for all functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need  to declare the functions and you do need the '__' prefix. E.g:

```
extern "C" _Quad __logq(_Quad x) ;
```

This works on Windows. Can't see why it wouldn't work on a Mac.

Comment: Why `extern "C"` for a C compilation?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issues using Visual Studio with Intel C++ compiler 2021.  Here is an example that I think may be a bug in ICC.

```
_Quad nn = 23.1416Q;
int mm1 = (int)(double)__log10q(nn); // there is a bug in Intel 2021 compiler. need to do cast here
int mm2 = __log10q(nn);
if (mm1 != mm2) {
printf("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!nn = %g, mm1 = %d, mm2 = %d\n", (double)nn, mm1, mm2);
}
```

In 32-bit release, it prints:
`!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!nn = 23.1416, mm1 = 1, mm2 = 2`

In 32-bit debug, it prints:
`!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!nn = 23.1416, mm1 = 4266, mm2 = 4267`

In 64-bit debug and release, it prints:
`!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!nn = 23.1416, mm1 = 1, mm2 = 2`